# Help with change in specific volume with time in piston cylinder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I have a piston cylinder assembly and I am trying to determine the change of specific volume with time, namely $\frac{dv}{dt}$, due to an inlet mass flow rate. My first thought was to put it in terms of the mass flow rate so... $$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dm}{dt}\frac{dv}{dm}$$ and I know that $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is the inlet mass flow rate. I could then use then use the expression $v=\frac{V}{m}$ to find $\frac{dv}{dm}$. My final expression came out to be $$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{V}{m^2}\dot m$$Unfortunately my professor told me the answer is $$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{V}{m^2}\dot m+\frac{1}{m}\frac{dV}{dt}$$

So I am wondering where I went wrong and why is there that extra term? Is there a chance he made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer holds in the case that $\frac{dV}{dt} = 0$. The more general situation (the one your professor seems to be working with), however, considers that $V$ may be changing as a function of time, and therefore changing as a function of $m$.

Try recalculating $\frac{dv}{dm} = \frac{d}{dm} \frac{V(m)}{m}$ using the product/quotient rules, accounting for the fact that $V$ can be dependent on $m$. This method should yield your professor's result.

Feel free to ask in the comments if you need more help.

(By the way, a quicker way to approach the problem would be to simply calculate $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{V(t)}{m(t)}$ with the quotient rule of calculus rather than decomposing the original derivative with the chain rule as you did. Nevertheless, your technique is valid if you find it more intuitive.)

Comment: when I used the quotient rule I reached
$$\frac{dv}{dm}=\frac{d}{dm}(\frac{V(m)}{m})=\frac{1}{m}\frac{dV}{dm}+\frac{1}{m^4}V(m)$$

and right away I realized I must have done something wrong because I have an $m^4$ when I should. Also, won't $\frac{dV}{dm}=\frac{d}{dm}(mv)$ just get me back to $\frac{dv}{dm}$ which was square one?

Comment: when I used the quotient rule I reached
$$\frac{dv}{dm}=\frac{d}{dm}(\frac{V(m)}{m})=\frac{1}{m}\frac{dV}{dm}+\frac{1}{m^4}V(m)$$

and right away I realized I must have done something wrong because I have an $m^4$ when I should. Also, won't $\frac{dV}{dm}=\frac{d}{dm}(mv)$ just get me back to $\frac{dv}{dm}$ which was square one?

Comment: Check your math on the derivative again. Regarding your concern with $\frac{dV}{dm}$, try converting that derivative into $\frac{dV}{dt}$. If you continue to have trouble, I urge you to use the method I brought up in the parenthetical note at the end of my answer - it's quite a bit simpler.

Comment: I used the quotient rule and obtained 

$$\frac{d}{dm}(\frac{V(m)}{m})=\frac{m\frac{dV}{dm}-V(m)\frac{d}{dm}(\frac{1}{m})}{m^2}=\frac{m\frac{dV}{dm}+\frac{1}{m^2}V}{m^2}$$

The only way I could think of expanding $\frac{dV}{dm}$ is by making it $\frac{dV}{dt}\frac{dt}{dm}$ or $\frac{d}{dm}(mv)=v\frac{dm}{dm}+m\frac{dv}{dm}$ which just puts me back to where I began

Comment: $\frac{d}{dm} \frac{V}{m} = \frac{m \frac{dV}{dm} - V \frac{dm}{dm}}{m^2}$. You accidentally left a $1/m$ rather than $m$ in the numerator. You're right in noting that $\frac{dV}{dm} = \frac{dV}{dt} \frac{dt}{dm}$. Moreover, since $\frac{dt}{dm} = \frac{1}{\frac{dm}{dt}} = \frac{1}{\dot{m}}$, you can write $\frac{dV}{dm} = \frac{1}{\dot{m}} \frac{dV}{dt}$.

Comment: WOW. I cannot believe I overlooked that mistake the entire time. Thanks a lot for the help. I also did it the way you mentioned in the endnote and I found it much more convenient

Comment: No problem! Everyone makes little mistakes.